# STM32F217VE MCU ethernet and USB query

Tags: microcontroller

STM32F217VE MCU has ethernet and USB facility.
Can these features be used through baremetal programming or is it compulsory to use RTOS for configuring ethernet and USB ports of MCU?

Comment: It does not require the use of RTOS, you are free to program them in any way you like. However, if you want to use manufacturer provided libraries, they may be made to run under RTOS, so you can read the manual how to use the libraries.

Comment: Additionally, the RTOS driver source code for those features can be a useful source of help for rolling your own bare metal drivers.

Comment: Don’t know the specifics of this particular MCU, but usually on top of the low-level Ethernet you need a whole TCP/IP stack, and that needs buffers, interrupts, timers, etc, which in turn usually requires some form of minimalist OS to handle all that. If you want to do it all from scratch there shouldn’t be any reason why you couldn’t, but it’s going to be quite a bit of work.

Answer (score 1):

All programming, in any language, with or without an OS, is ultimately converted to assembly language and becomes "bare metal" code.

So the answer to your question must be **yes** by definition...anything that can be done on a given microcontroller can be done using nothing but assembly language and starting with a blank slate.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not compulsory to use an RTOS for Ethernet and USB.  However, an RTOS might simplify the implementation of a complex networking stack such as TCP/IP.  With an RTOS, the individual threads/tasks can be sequential in nature.  Without an RTOS your application will likely be more event-based and use callbacks.  Which is better is a matter of developer experience and opinion.  Check out some USB and TCP/IP libraries and examples to get a better understanding.

For example, here is an excerpt from the [STMCube USB Device Library](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00108129-stm32cube-usb-device-library-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

> The USB device library can be used with or without RTOS; the CMSIS
> RTOS wrapper is used to make abstraction with OS kernel.

And the lwIP TCP/IP stack supports [three APIs](https://lwip.fandom.com/wiki/Application_API_layers).  The "raw" API does not require an RTOS but the "netconn" and "socket" APIs do require an RTOS.

Other libraries will have different requirements.